# Getting data from a void pointer using run time type identification

Tags: c++, templates, casting, void-pointers, runtime-type

I have some classes corresponding to some datatypes which are supposed to encode and decode the actual data. eg, 
`class MyInt32` will have function for encoding an integer value and decoding it from a stream of encoded bytes.
All these classes are derived from a base class, `MyTypes`. While decoding, after getting the value from the encoded 
string I put the value in the corresponding datatypes, eg `int` in case of `MyInt`, and  return the data as a `void *`.

At the 
receiving side, I typecast the pointer to `(int *)` and then dereference it to put it into the result.

But now I need a type for having arrays as well. In case of arrays I am using templates to say what the array is going 
to hold. that is,

```
template<typename T>
class MyArray:public MyType
{
    vector<T *> mydata;
    ....
};
```

In the decode function I will call the decode of the type T. But now it just returns  a `void*`. My array won't be knowing
 what the decoded type will be. So I can't typecast the `void *` and dereference it to get the value. That is,
If I take an array of `MyInt`

```
MyArray<MyInt> data;
```

The array '`data`' won't know that its decoded result will be a `vector<int>`. And it is preferable to pass the data as `vector<int>` rather  than `vector<int*>` 
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure each type that can be used as the template argument (`MyInt` etc.) has a `typedef` with a given name, such as `RepresentedType`:

```
class MyInt : public MyType {
public:
    typedef int RepresentedType;
    ....
};
```

Now you can use it in the templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class MyArray : public MyType {
    ....
    T::RepresentedType * something();
};
```

(I hope this is what you wanted.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use boost::any class for your purpose. It's the easy and efficient way to get the value of any 
stored data based on Runtime type Identification.

```
vector<boost::any> somevec;
boost::any obj= new MyClass<SomeTemplate>;
somevec.push_back(obj);

SomeTemplate ret = boost::any_cast<SomeTemplate>(somevec[0]);
```